# UISwitch keeps 'off' all the time but only on my 5s. In other devices works fine

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I am using UISwitch. When I touch that, Value won't change to ON in my 5s. In other devices it works fine.

```
func videoPlayerEnabledSwitchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) { 
   if(!sender.isOn) { 
        UserDefaults.standard.set("OFF", forKey: "someKey") 
   } 
   else { 
        UserDefaults.standard.set("ON", forKey: "someKey") 
   } 
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: `func videoPlayerEnabledSwitchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {


        if(!sender.isOn){
            UserDefaults.standard.set("OFF", forKey: "someKey")

        }else{
            UserDefaults.standard.set("ON", forKey: "someKey")

        }

}`

Comment: your code is right but may be possible in 5s screen to user interaction of switch is not getting

Comment: please add breakpoint videoPlayerEnabledSwitchValueChanged method and check both devices(5s and other) this method is calling or not

Comment: ok ok I will try

Comment: Kiso - don't show code in comments - update your question, and you will get a layout that people can read

Comment: "Value won't change" How do you know? You have no code that checks what is happening in User Defaults, and User Defaults does not magically tell you what is happening in it. — Also, your method signature is wrong for Swift 3; it should be `func videoPlayerEnabledSwitchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch)` (note the underline).

Comment: I can see that switch won't on. Even I click, it,keeps off always

Comment: @Russel - ok I will mind

Comment: @kisoSkiso Did you find solution for your problem ? I am also facing same problem with iPhone 5s.